# Driver for NVIDIA Corporation GK107M [GeForce GT 640M]

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 16.04, nvidia-optimus, bumblebee

I'm using Dell Inspiron 14R SE 7420 laptop which has dual / hybrid graphic card.

```
$ lspci | grep VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK107M [GeForce GT 640M] (rev a1)
```

Currently using Ubuntu 16.04 (x86-64) on my machine and dual booted with Windows 10.

```
$ cat /etc/lsb-release
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=16.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=xenial
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 16.04 LTS"
```

Does anyone can guide me how to install Nvidia bumblebee / prime on my laptop? and get both GPU working for me.

I appreciate any help and guide, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps it will help you

Run the following command in the terminal and type the password for the user when prompted.

`sudo apt-add-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa`

After adding the PPA, update your system repository by running following command

`sudo apt-get update`

Now to install the NVIDIA GeForce graphics driver run following in terminal

`sudo apt-get install nvidia-current nvidia-settings`

if evrything goes fine you will be good to go. Hope it helps

Comment: I try you method, seem my `sudo lshw -c video` ouput saying  `-display UNCLAIMED` after that